# Remove file from Dev C++ project

Tags: dev-c++

I want to remove some files from the project and the project browser.

I can exclude the files in Project->Project Options->Files by selecting the file and unchecking boxes ("Include in compilation" and "Include in linking").

That works for compiling, but I'd rather not see the files cluttering up the browser. How can I actually remove them from the project?

I tried deleting them from the project folder, then compiling, hoping I'd get a prompt asking me if I want to remove the files, but instead I got an error message.

I've right- and left-clicked (both single and double) every symbol in the project browser. The menu that comes up doesn't have a "delete" or "remove" option. I've checked every section and tab under Project.

I looked through the Dev C++ manual, and GCC documentation. I must have missed it. It must be possible to remove a file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Project->Remove From Project